# setting session in foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, session, foreach

i have a model in codeigniter that gets notification from the database using foreach loop.i want to pass the values to session using set_userdata but unfortunately i cant pass multiple values in to my session,please help.below is my model

```
function get_user_notifications($userID){
               $this->db->select()->from('messages')->where('receiverID',$userID);   
                $query = $this->db->get();
                if($query->num_rows()>0)
     {
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
          //add all data to session

            $notification=$rows->notification;
            $messageID=$rows->messageID;
            // $rows->messageID =>,



      $this->session->set_userdata('mynotifications',$notification);
        }


     }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you must start a session on each page where you actually want to access session values.

Answer (score 3):

add all the notifications to an array you instantiate prior to the foreach then add the array to session.

Also note if your using the standard codeigniter session there is a 4k limit on its size so this may not be the best approach.

Also, this is working on the assumption that your session class has been properly initialized...

I did my best to clean up your code.

```
function get_user_notifications($userID){
    $this->db->select()->from('messages')->where('receiverID',$userID);   
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $all_notifications = array();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
          foreach($query->result() as $rows)
          {
           //add all data to session
               $all_notification[]=$rows->notification;
               $messageID=$rows->messageID;     

          }
          $this->session->set_userdata('mynotifications',$all_notification);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a million guys,ts my first time posting and m grateful how helpful n fast ths thng z :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function get_user_notifications($userID){
    $this->db->select()->from('messages')->where('receiverID',$userID);   
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $notification='';
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $notification.=$rows->notification.',';
            $messageID=$rows->messageID;
            // $rows->messageID =>,
        }
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('mynotifications',$notification);
}
```